# Return wrong array when only one data in JSON

Tags: javascript, json

I have passed JSON from the server-side to the client-side. I have created a function to return the latest `rate` and `currency_id`. It workes for some but not workes for some.

When I use my function for `product_id` `1` and `2` workes well. It returns the correct array. But this not workes for `product_id` `3` and `4`. It returns an empty array. I have mentioned the used function below.

JS function:

```
COMNAME.prepEdit = function (product_id) {
const currencyIds = [];
const result = [];

const sortData = COMNAME.newCurrency
    .filter((item) => item.product_id === product_id)
    .sort((item1, item2) => item1.id - item2.id);


for (let i = sortData.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
    const item = sortData[i];

    if(!currencyIds.includes(item.currency_id)) {
        currencyIds.push(item.currency_id)
        result.unshift(item);
    }
}

return result;
}
```

Please help me to find my fault here. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not too sure what you are trying to do but, shouldn't your for loop be something like this :

`for (let i = sortData.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {`
Shouldn't it be `i>=0` since you also want the first index?

Comment: You are correct. The problem is there. Now it works fine.